# JavaScript/jQuery event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Some parts of my code that could be useful:
In 'index.php'

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/0/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/0/0.css" />
<script src="/0/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/0/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="contact.js"></script>
(...)
<input id="firstname" (...)"/>
```

(jQuery is version 2.0.3 and Bootstrap 2.3.2)

In 'contact.js'

```
$('#firstname').bind('keyup keypress change keydown oninput input', function(e) {
    alert('test');
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

It looks like something very simple but I'm not so use to JavaScript and can't find out why the event is not firing when I type in the input.

Comment: Is it inside document.ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the script is not in a dom ready handler, so when the script is executed the element may not be present in the dom structure that could be the reason

You need to add the script in dom ready handler

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('#firstname').bind('keyup keypress change keydown oninput input', function(e) {
        alert('test');
        alert($(this).val()); 
    });
})
```

Comment: Although I as well do not agree with `on` in place of `bind`. But for me `bind` was not able to work. By doing, `jQuery(function(){  
  $(document).on('keypress', '#searchinput', function(e){...`, the code started working. Hence, +1 for @khanh-to just for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `bind` is not recommended. Try `on`:

```
$(document).on('keyup keypress change keydown oninput input','#firstname', function(e) {
    alert('test');
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

If you delegate the event to document, this should work without waiting for the DOM loaded. Or you could wait for the DOM fully loaded as pointed out by @Arun P Johny and use direct event:

```
$('#firstname').on('keyup keypress change keydown oninput input', function(e) {
        alert('test');
        alert($(this).val()); 
    });
```

Comment: Why `$(document).on`? why delegate it to the document head?

Comment: I would also use `on` instead of `bind` but there is no need to add it to the document as long as you don't need to handle dynamically added elements.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder  provided op is using version >= 1.7. But this doesn't seem to be the issue here. I dont think bind is not available.. It is still available and just that it is recommended to use on for newer versions as per docs.

Comment: @PSL Yes it's not the issue.

Comment: `bind` is not deprecated, just superseeded.